# i want to count number of lines in a file and assign it to a variable. So that i can use that variable in my while loop

Tags: shell

I want to count number of lines in a files and assign that integer to a variable. I am using below code but not able to get through

Shell

```
#!/bin/bash
file=hostname.txt
n= $( wc -l hostname.txt | awk '{ print $1 }' ) #assigning number of lines to a variable but not able to do so 
i=1
while read -r line
do
while [ $i -le $n ]
        do
echo "==============$i=================$n================================"

i=$((i+1))
done
done < "$file"
```

```
==============1=================2================================
==============2=================2================================
```

Comment: You need no space between `=` and `$`

Comment: Rather than piping `wc` to `awk`, just write `wc -l < hostname.txt`.  By not giving `wc` the filename, it won't write it.

Comment: What do you want with the nested while-loops? The first time the inner loop will count to `n`, for all the next lines the inner loop is skipped. You get the same output with `for ((i=0; i<$n; i++)); do echo ...; done` without reading "${file}"

Comment: When you use `file=hostname.txt`, please use `${file}` in the rest of the code.

Comment: It does seem odd that you pre-fetch the number of lines, and then iterate over each line of the file.  There's no need to know up front how many lines there are; just iterate over each line, and stop when there's no more data.

Comment: The `$line` variable is input, but never used in the code shown.