# Not able to read file content one one

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash
file=test.txt

n=$(wc -l test.txt | awk '{ print $1 }' )

i=1

while IFS= read -r line

do

while [ $i -le $n ]

do

echo "======$i====$line======$n======" /* output*/

i=$((i+1))

done

done < "$file"
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide more detail about your problem.

Comment: @PriyanshuSrivastava : What does _one one reading_ mean? Also, what is your script supposed to do, and what is your actual question? Finally, your `#!` lines says "bash", but you tagged your question "shell". Are you interested in a genuine bash answer, or in one which would also work in a POSIX shell?

Comment: @PriyanshuSrivastava : Also note that your assignment to `n` can be easier written as `n=$(wc -l <test.txt)`.

Comment: I want to display entries that is there in text.txt

Comment: See your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57046574/3220113 and explain why you want two nested while loops.